# How to unshift an Array in another Array JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a way to unshift an Array in another Array?

I have an Array-of-Arrays

```
[["Sunny", "Hot", "High", "Weak", "No"],
["Sunny", "Hot", "High", "Strong", "No"]]
```

and all I am trying to accomplish is to add another Array

```
["Outlook", "Temperature", "Humidity", "Wind", "Play-ball"]
```

on top of the Array-of-Arrays, so that the final Array would look like this

```
[["Outlook", "Temperature", "Humidity", "Wind", "Play-ball"],
["Sunny", "Hot", "High", "Weak", "No"],
["Sunny", "Hot", "High", "Strong", "No"]]
```

unshift() only adds an empty Array on top of the Array-of-Arrays, so I guess it works only for items in a single Array, is there an unshift equivalent for Arrays?

Comment: Unshift works for me no problem. Can you add the code you tried, and how it doesn't work?

Comment: add using unshift `oldArray.unshift(newArray)`

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could unshift an array as an item.

```js
var array = [["Sunny", "Hot", "High", "Weak", "No"], ["Sunny", "Hot", "High", "Strong", "No"]],
    another = ["Outlook", "Temperature", "Humidity", "Wind", "Play-ball"];
   

array.unshift(another);

console.log(array);
```

Comment: That is exactly what I did but for some reason it doesn't work for me. ( It doesn't work on my pc :P )

Comment: it works in the console but it doesn't in my implementation, I must have something wrong in the scope of my variables.

Comment: I found the problem, but I don't understand why it behaves like that, I will edit my question.